# SIGABRT in main method - following basic tutorial of 20 lines of code... whats wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Very new to iOS / Xcode dev. With that in mind I am following this very basic tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases

I've stopped just before the "Changing Animation Facing Direction Based on Movement" section, so my code is fairly basic, we are just trying to loop the animation in the centre of the screen.

When I build, the build succeeds, I get an empty black screen from the simulator, and then it goes straight to my main method (as if I have a breakpoint there). This is the line it breaks on, with "SIGABRT"

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I have absolutely no idea what this means (from googling it seems like an unhandled exception has been thrown - how do I get it to break there with something more meaningful?)

The whole app is like 20 lines, i've followed the tutorial line by line, what gives?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on "All Objective-C Exceptions" to see where the error occurs.

Comment: put some code so we can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add exception breakpoint in your code to help you to debug this kind of error.
To enable them, go in your breakpoint tab and do this :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Geez *newbie facepalm*... Thanks... now i'm debugging :)